# Export only the last occurrence of string contains specific value

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have random values and want all of them which have w-* to be export only the last occurrence of them. Keep in mind that output can be different and dash can be repeat many times.

```
NAME
fair-3451-m
fair-3451-w-0
fair-3451-w-1
fair-4bb9-m
fair-4bb9-w-0
fair-4bb9-w-1
fair-4bb9-w-2
fair-4bb9-w-3
fair-sit-sed-1-4-m-0
fair-sit-sed-1-4-m-1
fair-sit-sed-1-4-m-2
fair-sit-sed-1-4-w-0
fair-sit-sed-1-4-w-1
fair-sit-sed-1-4-w-2
fair-sit-sed-1-4-w-3
prepr-uat-fair-m
prepr-uat-fair-w-0
prepr-uat-fair-w-1
prepr-uat-fair-w-2
prepr-uat-fair-w-3
prepr-sit-m
prepr-sit-w-0
prepr-sit-w-1
prepr-sit-w-2
prepr-sit-w-3
prepr-sit-w-4
prepr-sit-w-5
```

Expected view:

```
fair-3451-w-1
fair-4bb9-w-3
fair-sit-sed-1-4-w-3
prepr-uat-fair-w-3
prepr-sit-w-5
```

Comment: Would have been nice to see some attempt at the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT2:*** Adding solutions as OP changed the Input_file sample now.

***Solution 1st:*** Without sequence:

```
awk -F"-" '$0 ~ /-w-/{val=$0;$NF="";sub(/-$/,"");a[$0]=val} END{for(i in a){print a[i]}}'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** With sequence.

```
awk -F"-" '$0 ~ /-w-/{val=$0;$NF="";sub(/-$/,"");a[$0]=val} !b[$0]++{c[++i]=$0}END{for(j=1;j<=i;j++){if(a[c[j]]){print a[c[j]]}}}'  Input_file
```

***EDIT4:*** In case you want to get the very first occurrence then do following.

```
awk -F"-" '$0 ~ /-w-/{val=$0;$NF="";sub(/-$/,"");if(!a[$0]++){b[$0]=val}} END{for(i in b){print b[i]}}' Input_file
```

---

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk -F"-" '$2=="w"{a[$1]=$0} END{for(i in a){print a[i]}}'  Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** Adding one more solution which will give output in same sequence as per Input_file's `$1`.

```
awk -F"-" '!b[$1]++{c[++i]=$1} $2=="w"{a[$1]=$0} END{for(j=1;j<=i;j++){print a[c[j]]}}'  Input_file
```

Above codes are checking that `$2` second field should be `w` if you have any more requirement then we could change it accordingly too.

Comment: Will also display lines like `blew-m-3`, you should either match on `/-w-/` or use `$2 ~ "w"`

Comment: @Camusensei, I didn't get any output like `blew-m-3`? please let me know more details on this?

Comment: `host1, slave, pr, ...` are obvisouly redacted values, if OP has a real value ending with a `w`, this code would not work as expected

Comment: `$2~/w/` is different from `$2~"w"`. I expect OP to adapt this if he wants/needs to

Comment: @RavinderSign13 perfect, I now noticed that `$2~/w/` and `$2~"w"` are the same, but `$2=="w"` was what I was thinking about. Good job.

Comment: It's strange when have different values is not able to print them correctly ex.:
`NAME
fair-3451-m
fair-3451-w-0
fair-3451-w-1
fair-4bb9-m
fair-4bb9-w-0
fair-4bb9-w-1
fair-4bb9-w-2
fair-4bb9-w-3
fair-sit-sed-1-4-m-0
fair-sit-sed-1-4-m-1
fair-sit-sed-1-4-m-2
fair-sit-sed-1-4-w-0
fair-sit-sed-1-4-w-1
fair-sit-sed-1-4-w-2
fair-sit-sed-1-4-w-3
prepr-uat-fair-m
prepr-uat-fair-w-0
prepr-uat-fair-w-1
prepr-uat-fair-w-2
prepr-uat-fair-w-3
prepr-sit-m
prepr-sit-w-0
prepr-sit-w-1
prepr-sit-w-2
prepr-sit-w-3
prepr-sit-w-4
prepr-sit-w-5`

Comment: @KalinBorisov, please post these into your POST in code tags and let me know what is not working, could try to edit my code accordingly then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 already updated but not sure why should't work

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 it gives empty result

Comment: @KalinBorisov, your requirement is completely changed now, need to look into it.

Comment: @KalinBorisov, added EDIT2 solutions now, since your samples shown and actual were different, let me know if they help, I could see results are coming fine now.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 what we should change if for some reason want to get the first occurrence?

Comment: @KalinBorisov, please check my EDIT4 solution and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: Now I see what is the difference!